# res.render() into a div with express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am using nodejs with express and I'm trying to load an ejs into a div like this:

app.js (server side)

```
//SHOW
app.get("/courses/:id", function(req,res){
    console.log("requested");
    res.render('courses/show', function(err, html){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(html);
        }
    });
});
```

this prints in the console the HTML that is supposed to be loaded into the DIV

main.js (client side)

```
$(".course_link").on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({ 
      url: '/courses/asd',
      type: 'get',
      success: function(view) {
         $('#show_load').html(view);
      }
  });
});
```

I also tried:

```
$(".course_link").on('click', function(){
      $('#show_load').load('/courses/asd', function(){
        alert('ayy');
      });
});
```

this alerts 'ayy', but won't load the file

HTML (ejs)

```
<div class="col-sm-8 courses-menu" id="show_load">

</div>
```

But it won't load the HTML into the DIV, but it does console.logs 'requested' when I click the first time, it should make a request with each click too..

Comment: Try to attach a callback handler to check for errors while your `.load` function being called. You can do this like this, `$('#show_load').load('/courses/asd', null, function(responseText, textStatus, xhr{alert(textStatus); // });`

Comment: well, it now wont alert anything until I stop the server and when I do it just says 'error'. So now it seems it's getting stuck trying to load it?

Comment: Ok.. In that case, Can you try `alert(responseText);` in place of `alert(textStatus);` ?

Comment: `"/courses/asd"` can fit to `"/courses/:id"` ?

Comment: @DavidR yeah I alert those too, alert(responseText) says undefined, alert(xhr) says [Object object] and alert(textStatus) says 'error'

Comment: @MuhridinIbragimov yes, /:id is whatever, if type inmy URL bar localhost:3000/courses/blabsdlfsdofg it will render show.ejs

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `send()` the html:

```
// if a callback is specified, the rendered HTML string has to be sent explicitly
res.render('courses/show', function(err, html) {
  res.send(html);
});
```

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.get

Also make sure your PATH is complete:

```
var PATH = 'http://localhost:3000';    
$(".course_link").on('click', function(){
          $('#show_load').load(PATH + '/courses/asd', function(){
            alert('ayy');
          });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, although now that I alerted what @DavidR told me it says for alert(responseText) says the html that is to be loaded, alert(xhr) says [object Object] and alert(textStatus) says 'success'. But it still won't display anything

Comment: The path is fine, because app.js does console.logs out that something was requested. I can even print the html that is supposed to be rendered. Also, I found out that res.send() is necessary only if a callback is specified, the rendered HTML string has to be sent explicitly (in your link). Thanks though.